# Rails, Apartment gem in production environment, Error Message: Tenant Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the Apartment gem with Rails 5.2.1 to create a multi-tenancy application. In my development environment everything works fine but I do have problems to set up the production environment, because my hosting provider only allows me to use MySQL databases with pre-defined names like usr_webxx_1, usr_webxx_2 and so on.

My database.yml looks like below, so that usr_webxx_1 is the common (tenant indenpendent) database.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: usr_webxx_1
  pool: 5
  username: webxx
  password: <password>
  host: localhost
  timeout: 5000
```

To configure the different tenant databases I followed the instructions on the Apartment GitHub page "Tenants on different servers", so that my Apartment configuration looks like:

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.tenant_names = {
        'tenant_one' => {
            adapter: 'mysql2',
            encoding: 'utf8',
            pool: 5,
            reconnect: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            host: 'localhost',
            database: 'usr_webxx_2',
            username: 'webxx',
            password: '<password>'
        },
        'tenant_two' => {
            adapter: 'mysql2',
            encoding: 'utf8',
            pool: 5,
            reconnect: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            host: 'localhost',
            database: 'usr_webxx_3',
            username: 'webxx',
            password: '<password>'
        }
    }
  else
    config.tenant_names = lambda { Tenant.pluck :subdomain }
  end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
```

My tenant table which is excluded by

```
config.excluded_models = %w{ Tenant }
```

contains two entries name = tenant_one, subdomain = tenant_one and name = tenant_two, subdomain = tenant_two

The migration of all tenant database is working properly, but when I try to access a tenant in the browser by http://tenant_one.domain.com the production log shows following error message:
Apartment::TenantNotFound (Error while connecting to tenant tenant_one: Access denied for user 'webxx'@'localhost' to database 'tenant_one'):

I've tried to play around with the use_schemas configuration parameter, but there seems to be no difference concerning this error whether it is set to true or false.

Does anybody has a hint for me, what is wrong with my configuration. Thanks in advance.

Michael